# How can I get the class name of tensorflow models from zoo

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

recently I've been playing around with some of the models from the tensorflow object detection api zoo.

Mainly, the coco ssd_inception, and the oidv4 ssd_mobilenet. The problem is when it comes to label the detections on the image.

As an example when I run the oidv4 detector on [this](https://ibb.co/d2y9ycB) image it shows the labels that appears. [This](https://pastebin.com/cj58jBRt) is the classes files that I downloaded from oidv.

Another issue raises when I use the coco model on [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiVoa752L_mAhVhELkGHezgADgQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bieresgourmet.be%2Fen%2Fbiere%2F1127-packaging-for-a-bottle-of-375cl-left-at-obd.html&psig=AOvVaw3dM4T43nApJaeixq0np_P9&ust=1576775588612171) image:

```
label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Apparently it marks this image as index 84, when coco only has 80 objects to detect. I let my coco [classes](https://pastebin.com/x6gqcQng) file also.

And the code I'm currently using for detection:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2


# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to image")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.3,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())



# Leemos las clases disponibles en openImages
CLASSES = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('classes.txt', 'r')]
print(CLASSES)

# Le damos colores a las cajas para cada clase
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3)) 

# Importamos el modelo de red
cvNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')

# Leemos una imagen
img = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# Obtenemos las dimensiones de la imagen
h = img.shape[0] # Alto
w = img.shape[1] # Ancho
cvNet.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))
detections = cvNet.forward()


# loop over the detections
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
    # the prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # extract the index of the class label from the
        # `detections`, then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of
        # the bounding box for the object
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        print(idx   )
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # draw the prediction on the frame
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],
            confidence * 100)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            COLORS[idx], 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(img, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)



cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is because the `COCO dataset` puts `80 class names` in `90 class index`.

You can use the 90 classes index to create your labels and map with the predicted index value.

Below is the list of 90 classes for the `COCO dataset`.

```
classes_90 = ["background", "person", "bicycle", "car", "motorcycle",
            "airplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat", "traffic light", "fire hydrant",
            "unknown", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse",
            "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "unknown", "backpack",
            "umbrella", "unknown", "unknown", "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis",
            "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat", "baseball glove", "skateboard",
            "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle", "unknown", "wine glass", "cup", "fork", "knife",
            "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli", "carrot", "hot dog",
            "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "couch", "potted plant", "bed", "unknown", "dining table",
            "unknown", "unknown", "toilet", "unknown", "tv", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard",
            "cell phone", "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator", "unknown",
            "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors", "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush" ]
```

Below is the modified code which will resolve your issue.

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2


# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to image")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.3,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())



# Leemos las clases disponibles en openImages
CLASSES = classes_90  #New list of classess with 90 classess.
print(CLASSES)

# Le damos colores a las cajas para cada clase
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3)) 

# Importamos el modelo de red
cvNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')

# Leemos una imagen
img = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# Obtenemos las dimensiones de la imagen
h = img.shape[0] # Alto
w = img.shape[1] # Ancho
cvNet.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))
detections = cvNet.forward()


# loop over the detections
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
    # the prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # extract the index of the class label from the
        # `detections`, then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of
        # the bounding box for the object
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        print(idx   )
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # draw the prediction on the frame
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],
            confidence * 100)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            COLORS[idx], 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(img, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)



cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: @yieniggu - If the above answer solves your issue, please accept and upvote the answer, Thank You.